Retrieving cell data from Interactive Grid
Upon changing a value within my editable interactive grid region, I need to obtain three things:

The column name that the cell that was edited exists in
The value of the primary key of the row that the cell was edited exists in
The new value the cell was edited to

To solve this issue I created a DA that triggers on the change event, the target of which is the .a-GV-cell element.  Within the DA is the following JS Code:


//get column header
  let row$ = $(this.triggeringElement).parent();
  let index = row$.children().index(this.triggeringElement);
  let columns = apex.region('ig-static-id').call('getViews','grid').view$.grid('getColumns');

  columns = columns.filter(function({hidden,virtual}){
      return (!hidden && !virtual)
  });

  console.log(`The edited column is ${columns[index].property}`);

//get primary key column value for changed row 
  let model = apex.region('ig-static-id').widget().interactiveGrid('getCurrentView').model;
  let rowId = $(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').data('id');
  console.log('The primary key of the edited row is: ' + rowId);



This code gets me the column name and the primary key exactly as needed but I am struggling to obtain the text of the edited cell.  I am aware of changing the target of my DA to the columns of the IG and just using this.triggeringElement, but I need to get all three of the values within the same execute javascript code so I can pass them all to an AJAX callback.  Ideally within the same dynamic action I outlined above.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
